# Can i display my datas from my datadase in a Combobox?

Tags: python, mysql, tkinter, combobox

I am trying to display datas in my Combobox with this sql syntax :

```
sql = "SELECT helicopter_name FROM Helicopter ORDER BY id_helicopter DESC"
```

To display that sql syntax i done that :

```
cursor.execute(sql)
row = cursor.fetchall()
            for x in row :
                programme_menu_deroulant = ttk.Combobox(app, values = x)
                programme_menu_deroulant.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=W)
                programme_menu_deroulant.current(0)
```

The problem is that display only the first value  of my datas and i want to display all of the datas. (i have 8 datas)

Is it possible to display all of my datas in a combobox ?
And how can i do it ?

Comment: You could make your own list and avoid the loop, like `lst = [x[0] for x in row]` and create a combobox and then set its value to `lst`.

Comment: i done it first but i need to use this sql argument for call it later in my code

Comment: Avoid the loop, and do as said, it should be able to do what you need

Comment: You should create the combobox once and then define a function to fetch the required records and update the combobox.  Call the function whenever you want to update the combobox.